# Identifying duplicate rows within dataframes and between dataframes based on two columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row

I have two dataframes. For this question, I will create 2 fake example dataframes:

```
ppl <- data.frame(
id = c(1123, 5323, 5342, 1234, 6434, 2342),
state = c('ME', 'WY', 'FL', 'MA', 'TN', 'ME'),
name = c('Paul', 'Lisa', 'Simone', 'James', 'Ruby', 'Paul'))
```

and

```
ppl_2 <- data.frame(
id = c(1823, 5123, 5842, 1004, 6034, 1342),
state = c('MI', 'TN', 'NM', 'TX', 'OR', 'NH'),
name = c('Fred', 'Ruby', 'Estelle', 'Sylvia', 'Jim', 'Bob'))
```

I know that in order to identify the rows where two columns (state and name) are duplicated within a dataframe, I can use:

```
ppl[duplicated(ppl[, c(2,3)]),]
```

However, I am not sure how to extend this to find the duplication between two dataframes. To be more specific, I would like to identify the row where TN Ruby exists in both.

Thanks in advane.

Comment: You could just use a simple left join on your key columns for duplicates:
`### Convert to data.table
ppl_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(ppl)
ppl2_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(ppl_2)

### Join ppl_2 to ppl and deduce to duplicates between data.tables
ppl_dt[ppl2_dt, on = .(state, name)][!is.na(id)]

### Output
#      id state name i.id
# 1: 6434    TN Ruby 5123`

Answer (score -1):

Update after clarification:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(ppl, ppl_2) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1, .by=c(state, name)) 

id state name
1 1123    ME Paul
2 6434    TN Ruby
3 2342    ME Paul
4 5123    TN Ruby
```

Frist answer:
We could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(ppl, ppl_2) %>% 
  filter(state == "TN" & name == "Ruby") %>% 
  pull(id)
```

```
[1] 6434 5123
```

This will give the ids of TN Ruby

Comment: I would like to receive any of the duplicate rows between the two dataframes, not literally the TN Ruby. Thanks.